# Solving for $z$ in $x=\frac y{2 \tan(z/2)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve for $z$ given $x=\dfrac y{2 \tan(z/2)}$.

Wolfram Alpha gives me the solution, but when I plug the formula into Excel it's not giving expected results at all - if I plug the same $x$ value into the formula it does not give me the $z$ that I originally started with.

Hopefully that's enough information to go off of; normally I frequent Stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: You should not necessarily be surprised to get back a different value of $z$. Instead you should keep an open mind to the possibility that the equation is satisfied by many choices for $z$ even without changing $x$ and $y$. A formula that Excel can use will only produce a single value.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$x=\frac y {2 \tan(z/2)} \iff \tan(z/2)=\frac y {2x} \iff z=2\arctan \frac y {2x}+2k\pi$$

provided that $z\neq 0 \quad x\neq 0$.

Comment: Where does 'k' come from, how do I find this value?

Comment: @user3763099 For example $\tan x = 1 \implies x=\arctan (1)+k\pi =\pi/4+k\pi \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

$$2 \left(\pi  c_1+\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x}{y}\right)\right)$$

where $c_1$ is an integer.

Doesn't this work for you?

Comment: That's the formula I'm using, but maybe I'm lost as to what integer c1 is supposed to be. To me, this seems like an unsolved value, so I'm frankly confused as to what I should plug in there. Where does this come from?

Comment: $c_1$ is any integer value. You probably know that trig functions are periodic. $\tan b(x)$ is periodic and repeats every $\frac{pi}{b}$ radians. (Every $\pi$ radians if $b = 1$.) For example, $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = \tan \frac{5\pi}{4}$.